# Keep cmd working directory when running executable through link file

Tags: windows, cmd, windows-10

Take the following directory structure:

```
C:
└─Test
  ├─a
  │ ├─a.bat
  ├─b
  │ └─b.lnk
  └─c
```

`a.bat` is a batch file which simply contains `echo %cd%`, which prints the current working directory. 
`b.lnk` is a link file pointing to `a.bat`. It was created by Alt-dragging `a.bat` to the `b`-directory and renaming it accordingly.

Follow these steps:

1. Open `cmd`.
2. Execte `cd C:\Test\c`.
3. Execute `C:\Test\a\a.bat`.

   - This will print `C:\Test\c` because that's the working directory of the cmd instance that ran the batch file. The current working directory carries over. This will also apply to any executable file, e.g. a C# program containing `Console.WriteLine(Environment.WorkingDirectory);`.
4. Execute `C:\Test\b\b.lnk`

   - This will print `C:\Test\a`, the directory where the batch file pointed to is located at, instead of `C:\Test\c` like above.

What can be done to have the working directory of the cmd instance carry over to the run batch file (and other programs)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is to open the link file's property dialog and remove whatever path is in the "Execute in" textbox:
[image: Properties dialog of the link file]

This value does not only apply when the link file is double-clicked, but also when it is run from an existing process which already has a working directory. If it is set, it takes precedence.

Additionally, double-clicking the link file not produces `C:\Test\b`, the directory in which the link file is located.

I found it while writing the question but since I didn't find anything on this topic on Google I'm submitting this anyways so hopefully others (and myself, when I eventually forget how to do it) can find it.

Comment: This is what I used to do back when I used .LNK files a lot from the command line. For convenience I also added .LNK to the `PATHEXT` environment variable, to allow searching for commands in `PATH` without having to type the ".lnk" file extension.

Comment: @eryksun Yup, that's exactly what I have. Made my life so much easier.